# Understanding the meaning of this probability distribution

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, natural-numbers

I have problems in understanding the following assertion:

> We introduce a probability distribution on the natural numbers $\mathbb{N} - {0}$ as follows:
> $$P(I) = c_s\sum_{k\in I} \frac{1}{|k|^{1+2s}}$$

Where $I\subseteq N$

I don't know if I got the meaning well but is this the probability to pick a random natural number?

Also what is the $s$ term in the exponent?

Comment: I is a subset of $N$ as it says e.g. The set of numbers less than 0, the even numbers or the numbers between 0 and 10. I guess $s$ is just a positive real number but could be wrong.

Comment: The probability masses are $\frac{c_s}{k^{1+2s}}$ for all positive integers $k$.  The value $s$ is a parameter (presumably $s>0$) and the value $c_s$ is a number that makes all probabilities sum to 1. The probability of any subset $I$ is the sum of all masses in $I$.

Comment: @Michael Yes, $c_s$ is the normalisation constant. I was actually concerned about that $s$, which is positive. Why exactly we need it? Why $2s$? Is that a convention or what?

Comment: You do not need $|k|$ because $k$ is a positive integer, it suffices to use $k$.  You need $s>0$ to make all those values sum to a finite number, since $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k}=\infty$ but $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^{1+\delta}}<\infty$ whenever $\delta>0$.  You can define $\delta = 2s$ if you like. There is no apparent reason to use $2s$ rather than $\delta$. Possibly that notation makes something easier later on.

Comment: Now it's all clear! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The distribution you have is known as Zipf's distribution, formally speaking, for $s>1$ we have
$$P(I\subseteq \mathbb{N})=c_s\sum_{k\in I}\frac{1}{k^{s+1}}$$
where $$c_s=\frac{1}{\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k^{s+1}}}$$
reason by wich it is also known as Zeta or Riemann's distribution, since $c_s$ is expressed as a fraction of the Riemann's function. So the necesity of taking $s>1$ is due to the convergence of the Riemann's function.

Applications of this distribution can be enumerated in ranking areas as linguistic(Zipf), family incomes in a given country(Pareto) and many others. You can read about it in `Univariate Discrete Distributions` of Samuel Kotz, from Wiley Series in Probability and Statistics.

Also i advice you to take a look at Zipf's Law, although it is a little harder.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!